# Is my proof of the Uniform Continuity Theorem good?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

I tried to prove the Uniform Continuity Theorem differently than my book does it, using completeness and the Cauchy Convergence Criteon rather than the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem:

---

**Theorem** If a function $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$, then it is uniformly continuous on $[a, b]$.

*Proof.*
Suppose that $f$ is not uniformly continuous on $[a, b]$. Then, the set $$S = \{ x \mid f \text{ is not uniformly continuous on } [a, x]\}$$ is non-empty since it contains at least $b$. Let $c = \inf S$.

By the definition of the supremum, $f$ is not uniformly continuous on any neighborhood of $c$, meaning that there is an $\epsilon > 0$ such that any neighborhood of $c$ contains $x$ and $y$ for which $|f(x) - f(y)| > \epsilon$. By the Cauchy Convergence Criterion, $f$ must be divergent and therefore discontinuous at $c$.

---

Is my proof correct? What could I do to make it clearer and improve the style?

Comment: I believe you want $|f(x)-f(y)|> \epsilon$.

Comment: @7697: Yes, thanks, that's what I meant

Comment: Your proof is very confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally find your proof simple and clear, but you should start a new paragraph after "Let $c = \sup S$." and change:

> There must be an $\epsilon > 0$ such that for any $\delta$ there are $x, y \in [a, b]$ for which $|x - y| < \delta $ and $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$.
>
> By the definition of the supremum, $x$ and $y$ can be made arbitrarily close to $c$, which means that any neighborhood of $c$ contains $x$ and $y$ for which $|f(x) - f(y)| > \epsilon$. By the Cauchy Convergence Criterion, $f$ must be divergent and therefore discontinuous at $c$.

to:

> By the definition of the supremum, $f$ is not uniformly continuous on any neighborhood of $c$, meaning that any neighborhood of $c$ contains $x$ and $y$ for which $|f(x) - f(y)| > \epsilon$. By the Cauchy Convergence Criterion, $f$ must be divergent and therefore discontinuous at $c$.

This small change in wording makes everything much clearer in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

This honestly makes very little sense to me. The sentence that begins “there must be an $\epsilon>0$” isn’t what you want to say at all if you’re using continuity. You want to say that for every $x,y,$ and $\epsilon$ there exists a $\delta$. However, even fixing the quantifier error I don’t see where the next sentence comes from and why it’s important. $|f(x)-f(y)|>0$ only tells you that $f(x)\neq f(y)$ and that’s going to hold on any interval on which $f$ is non-constant. It doesn’t tell you anything other than that $f$ is non-constant and I certainly don’t see why you suddenly conclude that $f$ diverges (I assume you mean here that there’s some point at which $f$ doesn’t exist and the left and right limits tend to infinity?)

You never use any property of $c$ or the set you define in this proof. You say that $x,y$ can be arbitrarily close to $c$ because $c$ is the sup but really $x$ and $y$ can be arbitrarily close to $c$ because the real numbers get arbitrarily close together.

Can you explain the thought process behind the proof in some detail?

Comment: I'm starting by assuming that $f$ is not uniformly continuous, so there must be an $\epsilon$ such that for any $\delta$, $|x-y| < \delta$ is not enough to guarantee $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$. This is the negation of being uniformly continuous.

Comment: @user485573 You never said that anywhere in your proof. I think you’ve left a few critical ideas like that out. You also never specify anything about $x,y$. For example, are they supposed to be elements of $S$

Comment: Yes, I do, that's my first sentence in the proof... "Suppose that $f$ is not uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$"

Comment: And I also say that $x$ and $y$ are in $[a, b]$

Comment: The property of $c$ is used to guarantee that such $x$ and $y$ exist in any neighborhood of $c$ (because if they existed above $c$, then $c$ would not be an upper bound, and if they existed only below $c$, then $c$ would not be the least upper bound).

Comment: @user485573 It’s in your first sentence that we are assuming that $f$ isn’t uniformity continuous, but you still gotta say things like “since f is t uniformly continuous, there must be an $\epsilon$...” because otherwise it’s hard to follow where your ideas are coming from

Comment: Your explanation of how $c$’s properties guarantee that $y,x$ exist near $c$ must be included in your proof. Also, don’t you have that $c=b$? I think you should use inf instead of sup.

Comment: Also, your edits of the OP didn’t fix the critical error in the negation of the definition of uniformly continuous.

Comment: Ok, I made a few changes. Is it better now?